# PHP irregular characters: ���ˌ_s

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page that displays content after fetching it from database. The table has values as expected, but when it fetches and displays it is showing something like below:

`advertiser���ˌ_s`

The correct value in the table is:

```
advertiser's
```

I have done the following settings in my php file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

The database file looks like:

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

Can someone please tell what is going wrong.

Comment: I already did the settings as posted in the other question. This is not working, that is why posted a new question